# How to log events to a file in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I would like to log details regarding server requests into a file each time they occur.

What would be the optimal way to do this?

Currently using:

```
fs.open("./log_"+log_date.getMonth()+"-"+log_date.getDate(), "a+", function(err, fd){
    if(err) {
        sys.puts(err);
    } else {
        var logLineStr = JSON.stringify(log_line);
        fs.write(fd, logLineStr,null,null,null, function(err, written, buffer) {
            fs.close(fd);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What about something simple: `node index.js >> filename.log`. If you want something to split stdout and stderr, do `node index.js 1>filename.log 2>filename.error` or something like that. Use this in conjunction with util.log and util.debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [winston](https://github.com/indexzero/winston)

Answer (score 0):

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/fs.html#fs.write

> Note that it is unsafe to use fs.write multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream is strongly recommended.

I'm going to assume this is handling requests and it would be possible to have multiple opens/writes happening at the same time.

You're better off writing a module that opens the file once when needed and maintains a Writable Stream to ensure you don't have any odd edge cases/race conditions.

Comment: That is what I wanted to do but didn't find an example for how to use createWriteStream...